# Can I use a wood screen door to replace a sliding screen door on a french door

Tags: screens

There was originally a sliding screen door but I have not been able to find a replacement that fits or works properly. I would like to use a regular screen door to replace rather than a slider but not sure if this can be done properly.

Comment: I just ran into a similar situation. The right solution is to replace the sliding screen door. There are kits you can order and have delivered for about $100

Answer (score 1):

It can be done if you make/find a screen door the right size.

You would have to get a screen door track (top an bottom) and wheels to match that you groove into the bottom of door.

There are all different set ups depends on the brand you get.

EDIT:.

You will have to measure it and order a door to size.

Or get one a little bigger and plane/cut to size. Then fit your hinges.

Comment: I think he has a hinged screen in mind.

Comment: My bad must of missed read it